# Finding line height and baseline from Tesseract output

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I want to know how one could extract line height and baseline information from Tesseract's output.

Will appreciate any pointers to do that.

Thanks,
Vasant

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Tesseract.getUtf8Text().getBoxRects()
```

This returns an array of bounding boxes (Rects) for each recognized symbol. Their coordinates are relative to the bitmap you provided. You can use these to average out the line height and baseline.